# Retrieve role in jhipster immediately after Auth.login

Tags: jhipster

I want to send a user to a particular view after login based on a role that person has.  For example, I want to send a user with ROLE_STUDENT to a student page, and a person with ROLE_TEACHER to a teacher page.  Unfortunately, if I call isInRole in the controller immediately after Auth.login, that fails.  Specifically, in the login function (which I moved to main.controller.js so that the login dialog appears on the main page), I have code like this:

```
$scope.login = function () {
        Auth.login({
            username: $scope.username,
            password: $scope.password
        }).then(function (account, $state) {
            Principal.identity(true);
            $scope.authenticationError = false;
            $scope.account = account;
            $scope.isAuthenticated = Principal.isAuthenticated;
            $scope.isInRole = Principal.isInRole;
            if ($scope.isInRole('ROLE_STUDENT')) {
                $scope.state.go('student_dashboard');
            }
        }).catch(function () {
            $scope.authenticationError = true;
        });
    };
```

However, the isInRole method always returns false.  If I debug it, I can see in principal.service.js shows that at this point, _authenticated is false and _identity is undefined.

Now, if I comment out the isInRole conditional in the controller, so that the user always goes to the student_dashboard page, I can put isInRole code on the student_dashboard page itself, and it works great. So, it appears that something is happening between the time of the redirect, and the time the target page loads, and I want to know what that is so that I can cause it to happen and thus determine if a user has a particular role and then redirect appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your problem is with

```
Principal.identity(true);
```

This actually returns a promise  which does an ajax call to update the principal user, so to use the principal functions you will need to do something like this

```
Principal.identity(true).then(function(profile) {
    $scope.authenticationError = false;
    $scope.account = account;
    $scope.isAuthenticated = Principal.isAuthenticated;
    $scope.isInRole = Principal.isInRole;
    if ($scope.isInRole('ROLE_STUDENT')) {
        $scope.state.go('student_dashboard');
    }
});
```

Otherwise the current identity is undefined.